# How to rollback database if error occur during csv file import process?

Tags: php, sql, csv

I do an upload form for user to upload csv file. Data in csv will be imported to database. Data will be import to database if no error occur. I do validation on each row for the csv file. But incase row 1 and row 2 are already validate and inserted to database, row 3 have validation error. May i know how to rollback the database(delete row 1 and row 2)?

I try do `$dbcon->rollBack();` on else statement. But it does not work. The database is in InnoDB.

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

$dbcon->beginTransaction();

echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
        if(is_string($emapData[0]) && is_string($emapData[1]) && is_string($emapData[2]) && is_numeric($emapData[3])){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Diary(id, diary, remarks, status) VALUES('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
        }
        else{
            echo " There is data type error on row " . $row . " ";
            $dbcon->rollBack();
            break;
        }
        $res=$dbcon->query($sql);
        $row = $row +1;
    }
    fclose($file);
    echo "CSV File has been succesfully Imported";
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';}
```

Comment: Without knowing what class your `$dbcon` object is, it's hard to be sure what exactly is going on here, or what might solve it. When you say, "it doesn't work", what's happening? Do you see an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Another (probably preferable, assuming validation issues are relatively common) approach would be to do a first pass for validation, and then, assuming validation didn't find any problems, a second pass for database insertion.

Comment: Sidenote: You can just pass `0` as the second parameter to `fgetcsv()` to get all characters up until the end of the line, or just leave it off (unless you're reeeaaally confident that rows will never, ever, ever be over 10000 characters... which you probably aren't).

Answer (score 0):

first is to set your transaction variable.

```
$transaction = $dbcon->beginTransaction();
```

second is to commit your transaction after the loop

```
$transaction->commit();
```

third is to rollback transaction if failed during while loop

```
$transaction->rollback();
```

Here's your complete code

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

    $transaction = $dbcon->beginTransaction();

    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
            if(is_string($emapData[0]) && is_string($emapData[1]) && is_string($emapData[2]) && is_numeric($emapData[3])){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO Diary(id, diary, remarks, status) VALUES('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
            }
            else{
                echo " There is data type error on row " . $row . " ";
                $transaction->rollback();
                break;
            }
            $res=$dbcon->query($sql);
            $row = $row +1;
        }
        $transaction->commit();
        fclose($file);
        echo "CSV File has been succesfully Imported";
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
```